# AWS Pipeline deploy cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am looking to deploy new services on my ECS cluster using CodePipeline and cloudformation.

I was thinking I would make a template file in my project defining my service and task definition. Then I defined a deploy stage in my pipeline create a change-set. The problem is that since my template only contains my task definition and service (rest of stack is defined in a more general template) the change set wants to basically remove all resources except the service/task-definition.

Is my approach wrong, should I use the AWS cli instead and use "aws ecs register-task-definition" in a custom build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now I have to deploy another seperate stack with my service and keep the rest of my infrastructure in a seperate stack :)